# based on receipt type amount divide in three columns from one column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

[image]

i have 2 fileds in a table. Receipt No & Amount.  Receipt No have 3 types i.e Bank, Refund & Discount.  ired output based on receipt type in seperate columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One more clarification required sir if Receipt Number have GUN/BR/0001, HYD/BR/0001, VIZ/RD/0001, TPR/MD/0001, how can i write.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE to do it, like this :

```
SELECT Receipt, CASE LEFT(Receipt, 2) WHEN 'BR' THEN Amount END AS BANK,
                CASE LEFT(Receipt, 2) WHEN 'RD' THEN Amount END AS RFUND,
                CASE LEFT(Receipt, 2) WHEN 'MD' THEN Amount END AS DISCOUNT
FROM ...
```